# How to get Carbon localized date with locale digits in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-7, php-carbon, laravel-localization

With Laravel using Carbon for dates. Carbon has localization support. I have been using `$date->locale($locale)->isoFormat('LL')`.

Example, for Chinese, `$date->locale('zh-CN')->isoFormat('L')` to get localized data. It returns `1992年9月11日`. Is there any way to get the output with locale numbers.

Answer (score 2):

In the current version 2.41.5 of Carbon, Chinese language does not have `"alt_numbers"` (which would allow to use `translateNumber` to get the local number. Japanese has it for instance:
https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/src/Carbon/Lang/ja.php#L93

You may propose it as a pull-request.

Meanwhile you'll have to translate on your own:

```php
$string = '1992年9月11日';

echo preg_replace_callback('/\d+/', static function ($number) {
    // Here you can transform $number into an other representation according to your locale
    return $number;
}, $string);
```